# Dice game with two players

Tags: c

I have to make a game with two players. Each throws one dice and then the one whose dice number is bigger takes one point. This happens ten times.

Is this program OK? How can I do this game?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

    int i;
    int sumplayer1=0,sumplayer2=0;
    int dice1 = 0;
    int dice2 = 0;
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));

    for (i=0;i<=10; i++)
    {

    dice1 = (rand() % 6);
    dice2 = (rand() % 6);
        if (dice1>dice2)
            sumplayer1=sumplayer1+1;
        if (dice1<dice2)
            sumplayer2=sumplayer2+1;
        if (dice1==dice2){
            sumplayer1=sumplayer1;
            sumplayer2=sumplayer2;


    }


            if (sumplayer1>sumplayer2){
                printf("player 1 won");
            }
            if (sumplayer1<sumplayer2){
                printf("player 2 won");
            }



    return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: Sort out the indentation. Bung in the #includes and add comments. Couple of spaces here and there will not go amiss.

Comment: *"Is this program OK?"* - have you tested it? What happened?

Comment: Debug, debugger, debugging! There's nothing like watching your code execute line by line for learning and finding errors like you have. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

No.Your code is not okay. You have some mistakes in it.Here is the corrected code with all the mistakes corrected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> //neccessary headers

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ // You forgot this
  int i;
  int sumplayer1=0,sumplayer2=0;
  int dice1 = 0;
  int dice2 = 0;
  time_t t;
  srand(time(&t));

  for (i=0;i<10; i++) // use < not <= as you want to loop 10 times
  {

    dice1 = (rand() % 6)+1;
    dice2 = (rand() % 6)+1; //+1 because die values are 1-6 not 0-5
        if (dice1>dice2)
            sumplayer1++;
        else if (dice1<dice2) //use else if
            sumplayer2++;    //++ is much easier to understand
        /*if (dice1==dice2){ // No need of this part
            sumplayer1=sumplayer1;
            sumplayer2=sumplayer2;}*/ 
  }
    if (sumplayer1>sumplayer2){
            printf("player 1 won");
        }
        else if (sumplayer1<sumplayer2){ //use else if
            printf("player 2 won");
        }else  //There is a possibilty when both players get equal score
            printf("Its a tie");


  return 0;

}
//} Extra one here
```

Comment: The +1 after the rand does not matter. 0-5, 1-6 will work out the result the same

Comment: I know. But it is more convenient to do it as OP says it is a Dice game.